# Oracle regular expression REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle

I would like to replace a particular string format (ignoring the numbers appearing after ^).

Ex:
Here, i would like to replace all occurrences of string `[XYZ^abc^0^0]` where any digits can come up in place of `^0^0`, like `[XYZ^abc^0^0]` or `[XYZ^abc^20^10]`, etc..

Input string: `[XYZ^abc^0^1][dfgf^fgfgf^0^0][ggfgf^ererer^0^0][XYZ^abc^20^1][mkkfg^oorjj^0^0][XYZ^abc^0^0]`

Expected output: `[dfgf^fgfgf^0^0][ggfgf^ererer^0^0][mkkfg^oorjj^0^0]`

I tried many combinations including the below without any success:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('[XYZ^abc^0^1][dfgf^fgfgf^0^0][ggfgf^ererer^0^0][XYZ^abc^20^1][mkkfg^oorjj^0^0][XYZ^abc^0^0]',
                 '[XYZ^abc^\^[[:digit:]]{1,}\^[[:digit:]]{1,}\]'
                 ) "REGEXP_REPLACE" from dual
```

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `\[XYZ\^abc\^\d+\^\d+\]` with nothing.

Comment: Awesome... thanks so much! It works..!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the square brackets that should be treated literally. You didn't escape all the `^` characters, and you had an extra `^` character.

Also, `{1,}` can be written as `+`.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('[XYZ^abc^0^1][dfgf^fgfgf^0^0][ggfgf^ererer^0^0][XYZ^abc^20^1][mkkfg^oorjj^0^0][XYZ^abc^0^0]',
                 '\[XYZ\^abc\^[[:digit:]]+\^[[:digit:]]+\]'
                 ) "REGEXP_REPLACE" from dual
```